# Who should set up the Redirection?

Tags: redirect, web-crawler

Site A (e.g. oldsite.com) is on Host A, Site B (e.g. newsite.com.hk) is on Host B.

I want to redirect traffic from Site A to Site B. Should Host A or B be doing the redirect setup?

Both domains are active. How can i tell the search engine to crawl from Site B and not from Site A?

Comment: You can 301 redirect traffic from siteA to SiteB without losing your search rankings and this way only the SiteB will be visible in search engines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I get Host A or Host B to do the 301 redirect traffic?

Comment: The redirection should be from HostA to HostB. So you need to  setup a 301 redirect on your HostA. –

Comment: will this work? if i redirect via DNS and get HostB to configure the redirection?

Comment: Any 301 redirect will work. The easiest way to redirect your old domain URLs to the new one is redirection through an htaccess file. You can setup a 301 redirect on your olddomain/.htaccess.